# Can't add comments to my own questions answers

Tags: support, comments

I asked a question on SO - [How to correctly iterate application settings in C# using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679009/how-to-correctly-iterate-application-settings-in-c-sharp-using-reflection).  I used to be able to comment on answers but I cannot do so any longer.  The Add Comment link is grayed out and doesn't work.  I dont understand why I can't add comments anymore.

Comment: Strange. I [could add a comment just fine](http://i.imgur.com/ILYgf.png). (Since removed) What browser are you using?

Comment: Are you logged in as yourself?

Comment: Do you have any browser extension that would cause any issue? When users cannot comment, Stack Exchange doesn't show the link to add a comment; it doesn't gray it out.

Comment: I am unable to add a comment using Google Chrome.  I do not have any extensions enabled.  I am definitely logged in as busyspin via Google OpenID.  I have no problem adding a comment with Internet Explorer 9.